# Drawing a sphere in a room opengl

Tags: opengl

I have the code for a room provided to me, I need to add a sphere in the room. It goes like this:

```
PushMatrix();
       //draw floor,walls,ceilings
       PushMatrix();
       //draw some boxes on front wall
       PopMatrix();

       PushMatrix();
       //drawing sphere;
        glLoadIdentity();
        glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
        glTranslatef(0, ypos, 0);
        glutSolidSphere(2, 20, 20);
       PopMatrix();

 PopMatrix();
```

But all the walls etc turn red (and no sphere) when I do this. Why does that happen even after pushing another matrix?

Comment: `PushMatrix`/`PopMatrix` only affect the transformation matrix.  It sounds like you're expecting them to also save and restore the current color, but they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `glColor*()` sets the current color. This color doesn't change before you call `glColor*()` again. In other words `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` has no effect on the current color.

Thus if you in `//draw some boxes on front wall` don't call `glColor*()`. Then due to you setting the color to red by calling `glColor3f(1, 0, 0)` then everything is going to be red from that point on.

Considering:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluPerspective(40, 1, 1, 40);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

Then:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, -10);
glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
glutSolidSphere(2, 20, 20);
glPopMatrix();
```

By doing the above you should see a sphere.

Thus if you before didn't see the sphere at all. Then it's probably due to `ypos` being outside your view. If you were referring to the whole screen being red, then I'm assuming `ypos` to be around `0`, which means that it would be filling the whole screen (Again assuming you don't translate the view in any other way).

[image]

Comment: gluPerspective(80.0, 800.0/600.0, 0.1, 100.0);   If these are the arguments, what is a feasible position for the sphere? I tried using radius 25

Comment: Your code says the radius is `2` though? However if the radius is `25` (and taking your perspective into account) then something like `glTranslatef(0, 0, -100)` should push the sphere far enough.

Comment: Oh, actually the radius is not an issue, I was working with 2 earlier 25 later. Thank you

Comment: No I have yet to try it. The thank you is for answer to comment. I will post the result after trying

Comment: Ahh okay, was just confused. Comment when you've updated the question so I notice.

Comment: Thank you, I am able to see the sphere, but it looks like bread because of different scale of the 3 axes (z scale is very low)

Comment: Different scale of the 3 axes? I'm not sure I follow? You of course need to translate and position everything as needed.